# NestJS - Injecting the current request in a service from an other service doesn't work

Tags: nestjs

I'm trying to inject my request into a service but it's not working.
I have followed the documentation as below:

```
import { Injectable, Scope, Inject } from '@nestjs/common';
import { REQUEST } from '@nestjs/core';
import { Request } from 'express';

@Injectable({ scope: Scope.REQUEST })
export class CatsService {
  constructor(@Inject(REQUEST) private readonly request: Request) {}
}
```

I've noticed that injecting my service from my controller works, but not from another service. Is there a way to make it work in both cases?

Thanks

Comment: I believe this is because of you're using `scoped` services. https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/injection-scopes#scope-hierarchy. If the other service is not `Request Scoped` then it will error out.